# Problem with shutil.move - extra \

Tags: python

I have a log file and in the log, some of the files have errors, so when a file has an error I want to read its name (including path) and move it to another directory.

I can read the input file properly, for example one of the files is: C:\test\test1 i can find the file and I just want to move it. However, when I use shutil.move(filename,another_directory), even though printing filename shows c:\test1\test1, shutil somehow appends an extra '\' before every slash.. that is it tries to move C:\\test1\\test1. [Shutil.move is misreading the input path by adding extra '\' to every existing '\' ]

how do i fix it? Thanks !

```
import shutil
f=open("test_logs")
o=open("output_logs","w")
e=open("error_logs",'w')

another_directory= "C:/test"
for line in f:
    if line.lstrip().startswith("C:"):
        filename = line
        #print line
        #look for errors in the next line onwards. 
    if line.startswith("error"):
        e.write(filename + "\n")
        print filename
        shutil.move(filename,another_directory)
f.close()
o.close()
```

This is the error i get - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\test\\test1 (the file is C:\test\test1) and print filename shows c:\test\test1

Comment: Could it perhaps that you forgot to escape the backslash in `another_directory`?

Comment: the error is that when it goes through the input logfile, which has names like c:\test1\test, print filename correctly shows the output as C:\test1\test, i get an error saying no such file or directory C"\\test1\\test from the shutil command.

Comment: @Illusionist -- does `C:\test1\test` actually exist?

Comment: You're concentrating on something that is not even a problem. This is just how `repr` works.

Comment: piotr- its a problem because the shutil command fails to move the file and gives me an error.

Comment: You may be getting burned because you're not stripping the linefeed off `line` when you assign it to `filename`. You should do `filename = line.strip()` instead.

Comment: Another tip--use `os.path.join` for constructing paths instead of putting the whole thing together in one big string; this will ensure paths have the correct delimiters irrespective of the platform you're using. Instead of `another_directory = "c:\test"`, you would have `another_directory = os.path.join('c:', 'test')`.

Comment: @tmehlinger: Or just use "c:/test", which works on Windows and probably any platform in which the OP is interested.

Comment: @fred= I think my question was misleading, the input file has a bunch of filenames and if there is an error logged in the input file, I pick up the corresponding file and move it to a different directory. The problem is that shutil.move mistranslates the input filenames.

Comment: The double slashes in the filename are a red herring. That's just how Python prints the string because it contains backslashes. (If you were to give the string back to Python, it would need to have every backslash doubled, so that's how Python gives it to you.) In other words, *that is not your problem.* Stop asking how to fix that, and start asking what the real problem is.

Comment: Of course this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Several things are wrong here.

---

From your edited error messages, I see you're moving C:/test/test1 to C:/test/test1... this will (if I remember correctly) always fail on Windows.  Try a different destination directory for testing.

---

```
another_directory = "C:\test"
```

Should be "C:/test" or use os.path.join, etc.

---

```
for line in f:
    if line.lstrip().startswith("C:"):
        filename = line
        #print line
    if line.startswith("error"):
        e.write(filename + "\n")
        print filename
        shutil.move(filename,another_directory)
```

Both of these if conditions cannot be true at the same time, so you must be parsing filenames out of previous lines and then checking for "error" in later lines.  However, line.lstrip() doesn't modify line, it only returns a new value.  When you write the saved value (in filename) to your error log, you have two newlines – one which is still in filename.  Then when you move that file, it doesn't exist because "filename" still has both the newline and any leading whitespace you lstrip'd off.

---

```
another_directory= "C:/test"
filename = None
for line in f:
  if line.lstrip().startswith("C:"):
    filename = line.strip()  # Remove both leading and trailing WS.
    print "File:", filename, "(exists: %s)" % os.path.exists(filename)
  elif line.startswith("error"):
    assert filename is not None  # Do a sanity check as required.
    e.write(filename + "\n")
    print "Moving %s..." % filename
    shutil.move(filename, another_directory)
```

Comment: The input file goes like filename.... (next line) error !!  so I am trying to parse different lines.

Comment: @Illusionist: Yes, that's what I surmised.

Comment: @fred, thanks, your code is better than mine with sanity checks but it does not solve the problem of shutil.move putting in extra slashes in the input path (that was stored in the variable filename).

Comment: @Illusionist: Shutil.move does not do that.

Comment: This is the error i get - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\test\\test1

Comment: @Illusionist: That is the repr() of the string.  Backslashes must be escaped in string representations.  The given filename does not exist; if you check os.path.exists(filename) (as I do above), does it say True or False?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on `shutil.move`:

> If the destination is on the current
>   filesystem, then simply use rename.
>   Otherwise, copy     src (with copy2())
>   to the dst and then remove src.

... in which case, you want to use `os.rename` because both files do indeed live on the same file system. Instead of:

```
shutil.move(filename,another_directory)
```

Do:

```
directory, name  = os.path.split(filename)
os.rename(filename, os.path.join('c:', 'test', name))
```

From the error message you're getting, we can surmise `shutil.move` is failing because it expects the destination file to already exist, which it doesn't.